# Server-side Blazor users logged out when signalR circuit ungracefully broken

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have an asp.net core 3.1 server-side Blazor web site that uses the Microsoft Identity framework for authentication. It appears that whenever a user's SignalR circuit is ungracefully broken they lose their authentication state and have to log in again.

In these scenarios the `.AspNetCore.Identity.Application` cookie will still be present and unexpired. The problem doesn't occur if the circuit terminates gracefully (e.g. closing the browser); it's only in situations like a vpn disconnecting.

Here is the authentication section of Startup:

```
services.AddDbContext<IdentityDataContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("IntegrationDatabase")));

services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options =>
{
    options.Password.RequiredLength = 10;
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
})
.AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityDataContext>();

services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(CanViewDataPolicy.Name, CanViewDataPolicy.Policy);
    options.AddPolicy(RequireAdminPolicy.Name, RequireAdminPolicy.Policy);
});
```

Does anyone know why this occurs or how to prevent it? I would like users to remain authenticated until they log out or their cookie expires.

Comment: When the users reconnect with the VPN, if you have proxies involved that could be the issue. Just a thought, but [check out this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-3.1) if you haven't already.

Comment: I can see how the original circuit may not be recoverable after reconnecting to the vpn, but I don't understand what specifically is causing the user to have to reauthenticate. I was expecting that the user would reload the page, create a new circuit, and still be authenticated.